# The meaning of 鬓边不败牡丹

Tags: translation, meaning, phrase

It's from this song:

https://www.kugeci.com/song/MNnjq2LY#txt

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oGP9sY9WsbY&t=95s

> 是意中人
> 鬓边不败牡丹

Something about lovers.
I wonder if it's a reference to some Chinese literature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

牡丹 - Peoney has been regarded as "**the king of all flowers**" by the Chinese folks. 不败牡丹 is an artistic way to praise the beautifulness of the flower, which no others can compete with, wear on his beloved sideburn.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- 是意中人 is my beloved
- 鬓边 sideburns
- 不败牡丹 unwithering peony

> 是意中人鬓边不败牡丹 = It is the unwithering peony on my beloved's sideburn

If it were a weapon or something that fights, 不败 would mean "不曾战败" (undefeated) or "不会战败" (invincible)

But a flower on a sideburn is not a weapon and won't fight anyone, "败" here has to be "衰败"(decay) in other words "枯萎" (wither)

Comment: So, is it a reference to some Chinese literature?, as OP asked?